# Dynamic data on chart (Charts pod)

Tags: swift, ios-charts, ios12

I started to work with Charts pod (swift 4 language) and I'm going to create a very simple app that uses the line chart. In the examples I downloaded from the Charts web page, a list of random entries is created and then they call a method to display everything in the chart in a single shot. There is a more efficient way to put in the graph only one single record and updated the graph dynamically for example like in oscilloscope without redesign the full graph all the times? Thanks

Comment: This feature already there in the library you can add data in your current array and just update ChartsData will ref on Chart.

Comment: @CodeChanger what about performance? What happens if I have a lot of data? Is the chart fluid?

Comment: its text data so no issue with large data set as it will work with 100K data in my case.